# Populating a 2D array with my own input variables in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am new to C++ and have been hitting a snag for a couple of days. I need to figure out a way to input my own values into the array rows and columns as I go. For array T(I[500],j[15]), I need to input the row that is being looped and then add another loop inside that one for the columns of that row. PLEASE HELP!!

Comment: Are you asking how you would loop through a 2d array and put user input into the array?

Comment: Is that even correct syntax? T(I[500],j[15])

Comment: int T[500] [15]. like I said, im relatively new to this lol..

Comment: What about learning a bit of the language, and coming back to post what you have tried and doesn't work ?

Comment: Quentin, well I have researched for a couple of days on arrays and none of what ive read is what I need to do. So I wont even know the correct way to even set it up.

Answer (score 0):

To declare a 2d array and get user input you would do something like this:

```
const int ROWS = 10;
const int COLS = 10;

int numbers[ROWS][COLS];

for (int i = 0 i < ROWS; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter Element (" << i << "," << j << "): ";
        std::cin >> numbers[i][j]
    }
}
```

Comment: Bad usual failure not to check the extraction from an input stream (but it's a sketch)